# Cannot convert arraylist to string

Tags: string, arraylist

In the code below, sBar is an arraylist.  I am trying to convert it to String and then write it to file.  However, I don't know what I did wrong here as I keep getting error message saying:
    - NullPointerException
    - Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String

```
try{
   FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("stime.txt");
    for (Iterator it = sBar.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        String str = (String) it.next();
        writer.write(str);
     }
    }
 } catch (IOException e) {
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't convert a long to a string by casting. Change

```
String str = (String) it.next();
```

to

```
String str = it.next().toString();
```

---

Another way to write it would be to use a for each loop:

```
for (Long val : sBar)
    writer.write(String.valueOf(val));
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error clearly states, you cannot cast a `Long` to a `String`.
Java casts can only be used to convert an object to a type that it actually *is*; you cannot use a cast to convert an object to a different type.

You may want to call `.toString()`.